# static export for nextjs project and deployment with plesk

Tags: next.js, deployment, static, plesk

I uploaded my static build files using plesk => files => upload with the structure in this screen. and i make the root /httpdocs/build .

but it still read the default index.html outside build folder .

if i change the content of the index.html inside the build file to simple html page with any tag it read it.

i get this apache logs on plesk :

Error   152.42.169.224  404 GET /wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.0

Error   152.42.169.224  404 GET /blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.0
and more ..

what is the problem with the build index.html?
is there any missed configuration should i apply ?

i didn't install nodejs on server, and for test the build file i used "npx http-server out" and it serves successfully.
i tried to update index.html permission
and clear cache on browser